# Con qué fórmula de excel puedo verificar rango de fechas

Tags: excel, date

Con qué fórmula de excel anidada a la [FUNCION SI](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/funci%C3%B3n-si-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) puedo efectuar lo siguiente:

> ¿Si el estudiante ingreso en alguna fecha del **2017** colocar **"primero"**,
>
> Pero si ingreso en el año **2016** se indica que es **"segundo"**?

Es decir que extraiga el año dada un fecha, para que pueda ser evaluada por la función `SI`.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir una captura de pantalla de lo que te gustaría obtener?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a S.O. en español, te invito a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Luego edita tu pregunta para que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Si se tiene la siguiente tabla con formatos de fechas soportado por excel `dd/mm/aa`, `dd/mm/aaa`, `aaaa-mm-dd`, etc.

```
 |     A       |     B     |
1| 16/11/2017  |  PRIMERO  |
2| 07/05/16    |  SEGUNDO  |
3| 2016-06-07  |  SEGUNDO  |
```

En `B1` iría la siguiente expresión condicional que permite evaluar si el año es `2017` da `"PRIMERO"`, caso contrario dará `"SEGUNDO"`, van entre comillas porque son texto, pero excel las imprime sin comillas en la celda respectiva:

```
=SI(AÑO(A1)==2017;"PRIMERO"; "SEGUNDO")
```

Luego se arrastra la fórmula a las demás celdas: `B2`, `B3`,...

Finalmente vale la pena aclarar que la función `AÑO` es en mayusculas.